# VSCode WSL New WSL Window Command

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm not sure where to look, was going to post on VSCode Github but says it's better to post here. Just wondering if some change was made in command palette to the `New WSL Window` option or if it is rather something that may have changed on my setup.

I used to use it often to create a new window, now have to run `New Window` and then `Connect to WSL`. It's not a huge deal if it was changed intentionally, but if there's something I can do locally would be cool.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: https://stuartmccoll.github.io/posts/2021-06-08-set-wsl-as-default-vscode-terminal/